# Best practice for publishing state changes of an entity

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I have following model:

```csharp
public class Team {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string League {get; get;}
    public int Rating {get; set;}
}
```

Upon creation of new team in the system, I publish the event: `TeamCreated` to the service bus:

```json
{
    "MessageId": "33909eaf-56a1-4467-a01a-64b94f10490c"
    "MessageType": "TeamCreated",
    "CreationDate": "20-01-2016",
    "Payload":  {
        "Id": "11111www-56a1-4467-a01a-64b94f000111",
        "Name": "Toronto Maple Leafs",
        "League": "NHL NorthEast",
        "Rating": 100
    }
}
```

Next as this entry has been modified to following:

```json
{
    "MessageId": "33909eaf-56a1-4467-a01a-64b94f10490c"
    "MessageType": "TeamUpdated",
    "CreationDate": "20-01-2016",
    "Payload":  {
        "Id": "11111www-56a1-4467-a01a-64b94f000111",
        "Name": "Toronto Maple Leafs",
        "League": "NHL NorthEast",
        "Rating": 50
    }
}
```

As you see, he updated message still holds the value of all of the properties and not just the changed property which is Rating of the team.

My model, in real system has more than 50 properties and I don't want to create separate events for each property when it's being updated. Specially because it can be the case that more than one property have been changed in one update.

Is there a defined pattern for this scenario in the event sourcing architecture?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual answer is to forsake CRUD events, and instead describe the changes using the ubiquitous language.

To some extent, this is just a decoupling exercise; we're trying to describe "what happened" without being too invested in the way we happen to have implemented the state of the entity today.

To choose an example; suppose the 'Leafs were to move to Vegas; how would we describe that in the ubiquitous language?  We would probably say that the team *relocated* (changing home city, stadium), *realigned* (changing league), and possibly *rebranded* (changing team name, logo), possibly sold (changing ownership group).  So rather than packing this data into one `TeamUpdated` event, we would expect to see the change represented as multiple events, with logically grouped data sharing the appropriate event.

When you rehydrate the entity, it is responsible for recognizing the data in the payload of the event, and understanding how it changes it's own (private) state to reflect the previously recorded history.

Comment: Very well explained.

Comment: +1 to this. If you have more than 50 properties that would go on a ThingUpdated event then you absolutely need to split this up into the domain events that have happened